# How to perform case insensitive sorting with GNU make?

Tags: sorting, makefile, gnu-make

Given a list of files:

```
FILES = ABc AAc AaD aaa
```

Using `GNU make 4.2 (MinGW-W64)`, how can I obtain a list which would be case insensitive sorted ? Here is what I'd like to obtain :

> aaa AAc AaD ABc

I already know how to use `$(sort $(FILES))`, but this function is case sensitive and gives me this (I guess it's basically sorted by ASCII value) :

> AAc ABc AaD aaa

I am looking for an OS agnostic solution, so preferably a `GNU make` native solution.

The reason behind this is simply that I want to reproduce the exact same build order than another program, whose build order is a case insensitive sorting. I know that the Unix world is (usually) case sensitive anyway.

Comment: There is no native solution possible in GNU make; GNU make doesn't know anything about case.  If you build your GNU make with Guile integration you could implement it in Guile, but most versions of GNU make don't provide Guile support natively (you'd likely have to rebuild GNU make yourself).

Comment: The gnu make standard library has two functions, `lc` and `uc`, which can be used to convert case.   An ugly solution to this might be to do a foreach loop, create a variable `_CASE_INS_$(call lc, $(VAR)) := $(VAR)`, create a sorted list of the `_CASE_INS_...` variables, and then convert those to a sorted list of filenames....   (and of course this requires the standard library to be installed for it to work...).

Comment: Thanks for those answers, I guess I'll have to use an external tool then.

Comment: I knew about GMSL lc and uc but sorting that will give you a list of all lowercase or all uppercase files, not the original files.  I guess you could, after you sort, walk through the sorted list and look up the original name... but this would be _really_ slow for a list of any non-trivial size.